# Prebuilt WordPress Deployment

Tags: wordpress, deployment, saas

I’m building a web portal that my customers will buy from me and I’d like them to have immediate access rather than having to install it on a server manually.

At first I was considering using MultiSite but that wouldn’t work in this case. As they will be an admin of the portal, providing access to their members.

I’ve also considered using WHMCS but even though it’d be possible to deploy the files automatically the databases and config would be the same for every installation. Which wouldn’t work.

So my question is: Is it possible to deploy a prebuilt WordPress build to many?

Secondary question: I’m thinking that I should look to rebuild this as an actual SaaS, not on WordPress. Any thoughts or tips on that?

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be to can build an AWS launch config with an ec2 AMI that gets triggered with the correct domain/environment variables via AWS CLI. You can automate the whole launch. Hosting is going to get steep pretty quick, so if your subscription fee is small this probably isnt viable.

My second suggestion would be to write a WP deploy script. Maybe something like 
[Github deploy script](https://github.com/Mixd/wp-deploy)